# Are there simple examples of capacity-achieving block codes for discrete memoryless channels?

Tags: information-theory

The title pretty much says it all, but I am particularly interested in the case where the number of input and output symbols are equal and the transition matrix defining the DMC is nondegenerate. I am only interested in constructive/concrete examples, not (e.g.) a pointer to Shannon's channel coding theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first as constructive as it could get, capacity is only achieved asymptotically. That being said, you can take a look at several families of codes:

- Of course with high probability, for long enough $n$ any code of the appropriate rate can be used to transmit information with exponentially small decoding probability.
- Families of codes on sparse graphs achieve capacity. In particular, you can get [punctured LDPC codes](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~anastas/docs/tit06b_ha_r.pdf), [punctured nonsystematic IRA codes](http://ita.ucsd.edu/workshop/06/papers/132.pdf) (only for the BEC).
- There are claims that a new variant of LDPC codes is capacity achieving with [polynomial decoding complexity](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~anastas/docs/chunhao_thesis.pdf).
- [Concatenated codes](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Concatenated_codes), proposed by Forney, achieve exponentially decreasing error probabilities at all data rates less than capacity (polynomial decoding complexity).
- The new and very popular polar codes are also capacity achieving with [low encoding and decoding complexity](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.3756v1.pdf).

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Arikan's [polar codes](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0807/0807.3917v5.pdf)?